# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

Im getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null Source: X.push( check [ 1 ]);

what is the problem?

wspolrzedne.value = text typed in textArea like that: "2.4 5 1 67 15 67"

So maybe the problem is becouse titanium do not safe that string with \n as new line?

```
var coordinates = wspolrzedne.value.split( "\n" );
    var X = [];
    var Y = [];


    for( var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; ++i ) {
        var check = coordinates[ i ].match( /^([0-9]+.[0-9]*) ([0-9]+.[0-9]*)$/ ); 

        if( check == false) {
                var zlewspolrzedne = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title: "Niew?a?ciwe wspó?rz?dne: " + coordinates[ i ],
                buttonNames: ['Popraw'],
                cancel: 0
            });
            zlewspolrzedne.show();
        }

        X.push( check[ 0 ] );
        Y.push( check[ 1 ] );    

    }
```

Comment: Where do you anticipate the `\n` appearing in the string? Clearly your regex won't match the full string. FYI, you can use the `m` modifier on the regex to redefine `^` and `$` as matching the start and end of a line instead of the start and end of the string.

Comment: ...and if `check` is null, then I don't know why it wouldn't complain about index `0`. Something's missing.

Comment: i forgot about enters in my example. im typing into textarea 2 numbers in each line

Comment: im sure that this code work in normal js http://jsfiddle.net/fzYe7/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `textArea` doesn't care about `linebreaks`, its just a simple whitespace. So the solution is to split by **''** and then concat each two of them (or feed every pair directly to  the check array and check their content on the fly).

*Edit:*

Ok, so the problem is this line:

```
var check = coordinates[ i ].match( /^([0-9]+.[0-9]*) ([0-9]+. [0-9]*)$/ )
```

It assigns only one value instead of two.

Comment: you mean you can match them with "\n"?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is this line: 

var check = coordinates[ i ].match( /^([0-9]+.[0-9]*) ([0-9]+. [0-9]*)$/ )

It assigns only one value instead of two.